# Create a non-existent field in MySQL view

Tags: mysql, view

If possible I want to create a non-existent field in a MySQL view.

Say `select * from authors`

Then, if there is a field living and it is 1, I want to add a field `image` and assign it a value of `tick.gif`. Is this possible?

It is so I can easily use a rather flash grid program!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, are you looking for something like `SELECT count(1) FROM authors` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
select a.*, if(a.living = 1, "tick.gif", NULL) as image from authors a
```